# React variable component name - all lower case?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to render icons that are set in the back end for each service on the page. The data comes from an api and includes the correct names for the icons. I am importing the needed icons from react-icons before hand...

I tried it this way:

```
   //Services and icons
   
    var serviceICON = this.state.services.map(service => {
        let Icon = service.Icon
        return <tr><td><Icon /></td><td>  {service.serviceName}</td></tr>  
    });
```

This almost works - the only problem is that the icons are not rendered. Instead the html looks like this:

```
    <fabed></fabed>
```

I don't understand why this happens. The api delivers the correct name (=> FaBed), so why is this rendering as all lower case?

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

Edit:
The complete array for one of the services would look like this:

```
 id: 2
serviceName: "Hotel"
trip: 6
Icon: "FaBed"
created_at: "2020-07-08T06:45:02.239Z"
updated_at: "2020-07-22T07:52:05.066Z"
```

I am mapping through each of these and try to output the code above. As you can see "Icon" comes with the correct spelling. So I don't understand why it is rendered in all lower case...

Comment: Can you share the object shape for `service`, or the entire `services` array? Is it *actually* a react component?

Comment: I have added the array to original post... The array it self is not a react  component, the "Icon" is the name of imported icons from the react-icons npm package.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what is happening here is `Icon` is just a string so the react framework treats it differently.

[html tags vs react components](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components)

```
<Icon />
```

is converted to

```
React.createElement(Icon, {});
```

[Choosing the Type at Runtime](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime)

You'll notice here the key is using a map to match a string value with an actual React Component. For your case you'll need to map `service.Icon` to the relevant (*imported*) Icon Component.

```
import FaBed from '...';
...

const icons = {
  ...
  "FaBed": FaBed,
  ...
};

...

var serviceICON = this.state.services.map(service => {
  let Icon = icons[service.Icon];
  return <tr><td><Icon /></td><td>  {service.serviceName}</td></tr>  
});
```